# Почему не работает LIMIT в подзапросе - для профи SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT c.*, ar.ArticleName, ar.idArticle, du.DetailToUsersName, du.DetailToUsersPhoto, COUNT(c.idCommentToArticle) AS CNT, CASE WHEN d.Count IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE d.Count END AS CountLikes 
    FROM commenttoarticle c

    INNER JOIN (SELECT CommentToArticlePID FROM commenttoarticle 
    GROUP BY CommentToArticlePID 
    ORDER BY CommentToArticlePID LIMIT 3) AS articleComments

    LEFT JOIN article ar ON c.CommentToArticleIdArticle = ar.idArticle 
    LEFT JOIN detailtousers du ON du.idDetailToUsers = c.CommentToArticleIdUser 
    LEFT JOIN `likes` d ON (d.IdNote = c.idCommentToArticle AND d.LikeType = 6)

    WHERE c.CommentToArticleIdArticle = 11 
    GROUP BY c.idCommentToArticle
```

Почему-то оператор LIMIT 3 в суб-запросе не работает... Сейчас этот запрос показывает все строки из таблицы `commenttoarticle`

**Отредактированная версия:**

```
    SELECT c.*, ar.ArticleName, ar.idArticle, du.DetailToUsersName, du.DetailToUsersPhoto, COUNT(c.idCommentToArticle) AS CNT, CASE WHEN d.Count IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE d.Count END AS CountLikes

from (select * from commenttoarticle inner join (select distinct(idCommentToArticle) from commenttoarticle order by CommentToArticlePID limit 3) as ac using(CommentToArticlePID)) as c

LEFT JOIN article ar ON c.CommentToArticleIdArticle = ar.idArticle LEFT JOIN detailtousers du ON du.idDetailToUsers = c.CommentToArticleIdUser LEFT JOIN `likes` d ON (d.IdNote = c.idCommentToArticle AND d.LikeType = 6) WHERE c.CommentToArticleIdArticle = 11 GROUP BY c.idCommentToArticle ORDER BY c.idCommentToArticle DESC
```

**Ругается так:**

```
Unknown column 'CommentToArticlePID' in 'from clause'
```

Comment: Смысл запроса в том,  чтобы вытянуть последние несколько parent записей из таблицы со всеми children.

Comment: Какая работа? С чего такие утверждения? Запрос мной написан и вопрос задан, исходя из этого. А форматировать код желательно, чтобы удобно было читать.

Comment: Вопрос для профи, а задан как попало. Сделайте фидл. Какие данные вы выбираете, что от чего зависит, вообще непонятно (в смысле разбираться сложно).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем Вам `Group By`? Попробуйте заменить на `distinct`.

Попробуйте пересечение вложить во внутрь:

`select ... from (select * from commenttoarticle inner join (select distinct from commenttoarticle order by CommentToArticlePID limit 3) as ac using(CommentToArticlePID)) as c left join ...`

**Обновление**

Да, ac должно быть правильнее. Можно, конечно, и вообще без юзинга.

И как, помогло? Я бы для начала определил - это мускул не воспринимает лимит при перемножении, или всё же у вас дополнительные джойны и прочее всё портят.

Comment: Ругается на : `using(CommentToArticlePID)`, может, надо

 `using(ac.CommentToArticlePID)`?

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Хм, а как комментарии за других править? :-)